# How to adjust man page width

Tags: python-sphinx

Sphinx can generate `man` pages: `sphinx-build -b man` and the lines are wrapped at 80th character.
Is there an option to make the generated manual page width variable? By variable I mean that wrapping will be done based on terminal width like e.g. `man man`.

Answer (score 0):

The output is correct when I run man ./foo.1.